# prevent copying textbox value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 questions. first i wanna do something like these following codes that prevent (CTRL + C ) in a textbox but it won't work. it won't show anything in the messagebox.

The second question is how i can do something when the user pressed ( CTRL + C ) nothing will save in clipboard or automatically delete the value after pressing ( CTRL + C )

Here is the code :

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOT ALLOWED");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the `KeyCode` for equality against two different values, and it'll never be both. I think you meant to check for `Control`:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control) {
    MessageBox.Show("NOT ALLOWED");
}
```

As for stopping the copy operation, it should be as easy as:

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

And you can always clear the clipboard using:

```
Clipboard.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system level keyboard hook to intercept any combination of keyboard strokes.

Keyboard hooks functions are written in VC++ in .net. But for using in c#, there is pinvoke based wrapper library.

search for keyboard hooks in .net.

There are two type of hooks: application level and system level. as per your requirement, you can make a right choice.

I hope this can help you to proceed further.